# REST good design practice

Tags: python, rest, flask

I have a couple of database objects and I have to be able to modify all fields in them. So I really doubt about the way of implementing this.
I have two choices:

1. Implement one universal view for each object. For example like this:
   `/client PUT`. Where body will contain field name and field value.
2. Implement views for every field in every object(there are pretty much of them).

Well.. The second method is universal, it provides easy addition of new objects but may be a little bit complex: we have to check each field for existence, check value type for matching etc. The first method is clear and simple, but there will be a lot of views and a lot of boring work. So I can't choose one of them.

What are advantages and disadvantages of both methods that are not obvious and can cause troubles in future? 
Thanks.

P.S. I'm using Python's Flask.

Comment: What if you expose one table record as one resource, and in order to modify individual fields in the record use [HTTP Patch semantics](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5789#section-2)

Comment: Having a "modify" endpoint isn't RESTful; to change state, PATCH or PUT to the normal endpoint.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know. I wrote that here just because it shows well what I want to do. And not to mess with describing methods and etc.

Comment: Why ask about good practice with what you already know to be bad practice? I suggest you do some more reading.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I hope my edit is good for you. And now I'd be very great if you help me.

Comment: Do go and help yourself; there is plenty written on REST API design, on SO and elsewhere, already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Converting my comment to an answer]

As @jonrsharpe says, urls like `../../modify/..` is not RESTful at all. The HTTP verbs (GET, POST, PUT) should be used instead.

Given your situation and if it was up to me, I'd expose each database object (one record/row in a table) as a REST resource. Modifying individual fields in the resource should be done using [HTTP Patch semantics](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5789#section-2).

---

Assuming your object has three fields: `field1`, `field2`, field3`, and if I wanted to modify field2 only, I'd have the webservice accept something like:

```
Verb: PATCH
URL: /path/to/your/object #Does not have modify or any similar "verbs"
Data: {"field2": "newValue"}    #JSON is just an example.
```

Result (using JSON because its a bit easy to read)

```
{"field1": "oldValue1", "field2": "newValue", "field3": oldValue3"}
```

---

> For example like this: /client PUT

That may or may not work. HTTP PUT semantics replaces the entire object. So if you pass in just one field as in above, the result (ideally) should look like:

```
{"field2": "newValue"}  #The other fields are lost.
```

---

**NOTE**: The Patch data format that I have outlined in my answer is wrong. [Please read this article](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/) on how the data should be (Thanks @Jim!).

Comment: Thanks. Second part is precisely what I'm asking about.

Comment: That's not really how `PATCH` works – the request body should be a set of changes, not simply arbitrary fields.  As the part of the spec. you link to states – this should be a patch document.  There's more discussion about this in [this article](http://williamdurand.fr/2014/02/14/please-do-not-patch-like-an-idiot/).

Comment: @Jim: I just skimmed through it. Great article. I guess I was patching like an idiot after all!